# Kafka Connect JDBC Sink quote.sql.identifiers not working

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to use Kafka Connect to sync data from an old DB2 database to a Postgres database using the JDBC Source and Sink Connectors. It works fine, but only if I am very strict on the case I use for table names.

For example, I have a table in DB2 called ACTION and it also exists in Postgres with the same columns, etc. The only difference is in DB2 it's upper case `ACTION` and in Postgres it's lowercase `action`.

Here's a sink file that works:

```
{
    "name": "jdbc_sink_pg_action",
    "config": {
        "_comment": "The JDBC connector class",
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",

        "_comment": "How to serialise the value of keys ",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",


        "_comment": "As above, but for the value of the message. Note that these key/value serialisation settings can be set globally for Connect and thus omitted for individual connector configs to make them shorter and clearer",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",

        "_comment": " --- JDBC-specific configuration below here  --- ",

        "_comment": "JDBC connection URL.",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5435/postgres",
        "connection.user": "postgres",
        "connection.password": "*****",

        "topics": "ACTION",
        "table.name.format": "action",

        "_comment": "The insertion mode to use",
        "insert.mode": "upsert",

        "_comment": "The primary key mode",
        "pk.mode": "record_value",

        "_comment": "List of comma-separated primary key field names. The runtime interpretation of this config depends on the pk.mode",
        "pk.fields": "ACTION_ID",

        "quote.sql.identifiers": "never"
    }
}
```

This is ok, but it's not very flexible. For example, I have many other tables and I'd like to sync them too, but I don't want to create a connector file for each and every table. So I try using:

`"table.name.format": "${topic}",`

When I do this, I get the following error in the logs when I try to load my sink connector:

> Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Table "ACTION"
>    is missing and auto-creation is disabled

So it seems to me that `"quote.sql.identifiers": "never"` is not actually working otherwise the query the sink connector is doing would be unquoted and it would allow for any case (it would convert to lower).

Why isn't this working? I get the same results if I just use `ACTION` as the table.name.format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PostgreSQL table name (`action`) is not equal to the topic name (`ACTION`).
Kafka Connect JDBC Connector [uses](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/blob/da9619af1d7442dd91793dbc4dc65b8e7414e7b5/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/jdbc/dialect/GenericDatabaseDialect.java#L549) `getTables()` method to check if a table exists, where `tableNamePattern` param is case sensitive (according the docs: `must match the table name as it is stored in the database`).

You can use [`ChangeTopicCase`](https://jcustenborder.github.io/kafka-connect-documentation/projects/kafka-connect-transform-common/transformations/ChangeTopicCase.html) transformation from [Kafka Connect Common Transformations](https://www.confluent.io/hub/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-transform-common).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll try that! So I can just use this in my sink file and it'll grab the topic and change it before kafka connect reads "${topic}" in table.name.format? I may also use the RegexRouter to drop a prefix, I assume these would work fine together on the sink? https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/regexrouter.html

Comment: Yes, SMTs transform outbound messages before they are sent to a sink connector. And you can use RegexRouter SMT together since Kafka Connect supports chained transformations  https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/valuetokey.html#chained-transformation

Comment: Cool, make sense. Last question on this, when you say "before they are sent to a sink connector", you're not saying this transform would be in the source file? It'd be in the sink right? Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome! It's about sink connector. So you can imagine message path of Sink connector for your case smth like this: `Kafka -> SMT Chain -> JDBC -> Postgres` This info is from Confluent docs (https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/index.html#kconnect-long-transformations): > SMTs transform inbound messages after a source connector has produced them, but before they are written to Kafka. SMTs transform outbound messages before they are sent to a sink connector.

Comment: Also please read this very useful article about SMT https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-single-message-transformation-tutorial-with-examples/